creating dji CloudApi dev environment
We are wanting to develop a DJI Cloud API application for our M30T that synchronizes drone position on a web portal with our other Search and Rescue assets.  I've started with the Cloud API docker container but not sure what we need for set up on the drone-side.
Obviously we need to be able to simulate a moving drone so the lat/lon moves around, so can we somehow leverage DJI Assistant 2 (Enterprise)? Do we need the physical drone and/or controller present?  We definitely want to address any risk of operating a drone (even just powered on) indoors, if we can.
Any advise on what configurations work for this kind of development would be appreciated.
